# Turn 3 listboxes into 1 3-column listbox?

Tags: excel, vba

The following code searches column A(sorted) for an item# and each time it finds it, the corresponding B, C & D column are entered into 3 listboxes. I would like to use a 3-column listbox. Any help?

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()



    Dim Response As Long
    Dim NotFound As Integer
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim str1 As String, str2 As String, str3 As String

    NotFound = 0

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Items").Activate

    Response = Val("0" & Replace(txtItemNumber.Text, "-", ""))

    If Response <> False Then

        With ActiveSheet
            arr = .Range("A2:D" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        End With

        For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
            If arr(i, 1) = Response Then
                str1 = IIf(str1 = "", arr(i, 2), str1 & "|" & arr(i, 2))
                str2 = IIf(str2 = "", arr(i, 3), str2 & "|" & arr(i, 3))
                str3 = IIf(str3 = "", arr(i, 4), str3 & "|" & arr(i, 4))
            End If
        Next

        If str1 = "" Then
            MsgBox "Item Number Not Found!", vbExclamation
            NotFound = 1
        Else
            Frame1.Visible = True
            ListBox1.List = Split(str1, "|")
            ListBox2.List = Split(str2, "|")
            ListBox3.List = Split(str3, "|")
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Thanks for any help...

Comment: Why not try using the multi-column list, then post back with your code if you run into problems ?  First you try, *then* we help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

Change:

```
    If str1 = "" Then
        MsgBox "Item Number Not Found!", vbExclamation
        NotFound = 1
    Else
        Frame1.Visible = True
        ListBox1.List = Split(str1, "|")
        ListBox2.List = Split(str2, "|")
        ListBox3.List = Split(str3, "|")
    End If
```

to:

```
If str1 = "" Then
  MsgBox "Item Number Not Found!", vbExclamation
  NotFound = 1
Else
  Frame1.Visible = True
  ListBox1.Clear 'to avoid errors
  ListBox1.ColumnCount = 3

  For i = 0 To UBound(Split(str1, "|"))
    ListBox1.AddItem Split(str1, "|")(i)
    ListBox1.List(i, 1) = Split(str2, "|")(i)
    ListBox1.List(i, 2) = Split(str3, "|")(i)
  Next
End If
```

hint: you may change `ColumnWidths`

however... to leave you some work, i suggest to merge it with your `arr`-part...
just using my solution would be a waste :D

Comment: I opted to leave the program alone for now... I have written much more into it since the question posted but will try back after completion of original to improve it with your help and advice